# Dynamically import relative path module and instantiate class with parameter

Tags: python-2.7, class, oop, dynamic, import

OK a possible duplicate, but if not how can I dynamically import a module and instantiate with a parameter?

I have a class module in a file `food/healthyfood/fruits.py`:

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, kind):
        self.kind = kind
```

now I need to import this class dynamically by just a string 'Fruit' and instantiate it with a parameter.

**Static loading method in the file located in food package folder:**

```
from food.healthyfood import fruits
fruit = fruits.Fruit('apple')
```

**Dynamic loading method in the file located in food package folder:**

```
fruitClass = getattr(importlib.import_module("food.healthyfood.fruits"), "Fruit")
fruit_inst = fruitClass('apple')
```

I get a package not found error, what am I doing wrong?
Also food & healthyfood are python package folders and has `__init__.py` in each.